# MySQL> Best Practice for Escaping the Backslash Character Itself

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We populate a database by scraping some publicly available data.  Occasionally a datum ends with the backslash character (e.g. `SE-3257fs \REV-1\`).  Is `\\` the best practice to handle this type of situation?  One of our colleagues suggests replacing all instances of `\` in the scraped data with the HTML entity code `&#92;`.  The argument is that it will not cause any issues, plus it will "look proper" when rendered in HTML.

Comment: What are you doing with the SQL held data? If it's ONLY beind displayed on HTML then you can replace with the entity code, but if you're dumping out elsewhere (ie CSV export) then you'll need to do some sort of additional HTML entity decoding for these situations

Comment: Overall best practise would be to retain the original data and escape it as nessecary. In certain situations (ie PDO PHP interfaces) MySQL will auto-escape these characters for you.

Comment: Based on the comments received, we have decided to go with the escaping route, rather than the HTML entity code route.

Comment: @Martin - turn your Comments into an Answer.  (And fix the spelling.)

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing with the SQL held data?

If it's *ONLY* being displayed on HTML then you *could* replace this with the entity code, but if you are ever dumping out elsewhere (ie CSV export) then you would need to do some sort of additional HTML entity decoding for these situations - so you would in effect be making more work for yourself.

Overall **best practise** would be to retain the *original* data and escape it as necessary. In certain situations (ie PHP PDO prepared statements) MySQL will auto-escape these character strings for you so you simply don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Eh?  I don't think there is any auto-escape in this context.

Comment: @RickJames PDO prepared statements will escape data strings

Comment: To get past PHP, you must escape backslash and single quote or double quote (whichever you are using).  PDO will then re-escape those 3 characters.  (Maybe some control characters get escaped, too.)

Comment: @RickJames I only posted this as an answer from your comment on the question,  as I wasn't certain of the details. Maybe it's easier if you simply edit and clarify this answer. `:-)`